# Sendmail: Only allow specified hosts to send and from one specified domain

Tags: sendmail

I am trying to configure sendmail to only allow sending from specific hosts but in addition I want to only allow mail from specific domain.. Sending from any other domain would be blocked.

I have managed to work out how to allow only from specific hosts, by using access file.

Connect:x.x.x.x RELAY
but I want to use something like

FROM:specificdomain.com OK
I think once a rule matches in access_db matches it will allow it... So the FROM line will anything to send an email if its from the specified domain.

Is there a way to combine rules in access_db...

Connect:x.x.x.x FROM:specificdomain.com RELAY

I have searched and cannot find anything on this.